# Checking if string is ending with the provided parameter or not

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to create a basic algorithm that checks if the string is ending with a provided parameter.

**My problem is my code works only if the provided parameter is a single character.**

Here is my code :

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
   let arr = str.split('');
    if(target === arr[arr.length-1]){
        return true;
    }else
        return false;

  }
  
  confirmEnding("Sebastian", "n");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.prototype.endsWith`.

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.endsWith(target);
}
```

Manually, slice the target's length off.

```js
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  return str.slice(-1 * target.length) === target;
}

console.log(confirmEnding("Sebastian", "ian"));
```